# If I change my Google e-mail from Gmail to an external e-mail, will all my content and apps be preserved?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Google account that I use with many of Google's services, including Maps, Books, search history, YouTube, Drive, Docs, Sheets, Photos, etc. Google DNS, Google Cloud Platform, Google APIs, etc. and several others. But the e-mail I have associated with that account (as the account name) is not one that I use, or would like to use, and I would like to keep all the services as they are, and simply associate a different e-mail with all of them.

I gather, from the [instructions provided by Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en) that this is possible to do by simply deleting Gmail from my account, and supplying the desired e-mail when prompted; but I want to be **absolutely sure** that I'm understanding what happens when I do this, so I'd like to hear from people who have *actually accomplished* this that it works. Specifically:

1. If I [delete my Gmail account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/61177), what happens next. Will I just be asked to supply an existing e-mail as a replacement?
2. Will all of my existing content and accounts (all of those above, search history, bookmarks, etc.) associated with the deleted Gmail account be preserved and simply now be associated with the newly supplied e-mail account?
3. Will links that I shared from the old e-mail (e.g. to Docs) continue to work?
4. What will happen to cached or downloaded content associated with mobile apps (e.g. Photos or Docs on iOS)? Will these simply be reassigned to the new e-mail or will they need to be re-downloaded?

In short, I want to be sure that if I change the e-mail associated with an account from a Gmail account to a non-Gmail account, following Google's [instructions](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en), all of my content, apps, and relationships will be preserved. Can someone with direct experience confirm this?

Comment: i cannot answer your answer direct, but i had an google apps account which i deleted and lost my data - but when creating the same account within 30 days again, all your account data like mails etc. are restored

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to worry as all of the data is stored in phone and synced with the Google account. This means that those settings and bookmarks can be accessed anywhere from where you login BUT along with this they are also part of your phone cache and memory. So the bookmarks and other settings won't be lost even if you delete your Google Account. Moreover whenever you will login from your new Google Account those bookmarks and settings will also get synced to that account.

Answer to Your questions

1. Once you delete your Google account you will get an error on mobile and it will ask to login from an existing account or to make a new Google account.
2. Yes, all of your settings and bookmarks will be saved as they are also on the phone memory(as discussed above) . If you want to associate those settings to new Google account you just need to login from that account(after you have deleted your current account)
3. Yes all of your links will continoue to work as all of them are dynamic links.
4. Your cached data will remain saved. You dont need to reinstall any app. All of your data will remain safe.

Comment: Also, can you clarify? This isn't about a mobile phone scenario. I'm asking what happens in the management of these accounts. So if I perform step 1 in a Web browser, and no phone is (currently) involved, what happens in step 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let me clear you about all your doubts. Explaining with screenshots so that you don't have anymore confusions:

> 1. If I delete my Gmail account, what happens next. Will I just be asked to supply an existing e-mail as a replacement?

I assume you have visited **https://myaccount.google.com/** and logged in there and clicked on `Delete your account or services` under `Account preferences` tab, where you will see 2 options. In your case, you wanted to replace your `Gmail` account with another mail service keeping all other services and settings intact. So, select the 1st option stating `Delete products`. What this option does is you can manually remove one or more google services which includes `Gmail` too but not the whole `Google account`.

**N.B.:** `Google Account` and `Gmail` id are not the same account. `Gmail` is just one of the services of many services provided by `Google Account`.

When you click on `Delete products`, for extra security you will have to sign in again providing the password of your gmail account. Next after logging in you will see something like this:

[image]

By clicking `Download Data` option you can take the backup of all the data including `Mail`, `Notes`, `Searches`, `Location History`, `Blogs` and so on attached with your google account. It is wise to keep a backup of those in case something goes wrong.

Now when we will click on `Delete` icon beside `Gmail`, you will see something like this:

[image]

SO, you must have to provide another non Gmail new e-mail id, without which the present `Gmail` account will not be deleted. After that they will send a confirmation e-mail to your newly provided E-mail id. After that your present `Gmail` account will be deleted whether all other services will be attached to your new E-mail.

> 2. Will all of my existing content and accounts (all of those above, search history, bookmarks, etc.) associated with the deleted Gmail
>      account be preserved and simply now be associated with the newly
>      supplied e-mail account?

Yes, they will be associated with new one. But only the mails will not be supplied to your new E-mail id as usual.

> 3. Will links that I shared from the old e-mail (e.g. to Docs) continue
>      to work?

Yes, the links will work. The links are created from `Google Docs` or similar services but not from gmail. So, the links are preserved as it was.

> 4. What will happen to cached or downloaded content associated with
>      mobile apps (e.g. Photos or Docs on iOS)? Will these simply be
>      reassigned to the new e-mail or will they need to be re-downloaded?

Not pretty sure about this matter as I have no iOS compatible device and I also don't know whether iOS devices use Gmail as the app store access mail. But if would be Android, all the apps downloaded from Play Store associated with the previous account will be as it was. And for appdata (cached or downloaded content), I think you may have to re-download them or simply re-syncing them may solve the issue. But surely you will not loose any of your contents.

Comment: Can you clarify "After that your present Gmail account will be deleted whether all other services will be attached to your new E-mail." and "But only the mails will not be supplied to your new E-mail id as usual."?

Comment: `"After that your present Gmail account will be deleted whether all other services will be attached to your new E-mail."` means you will no longer be able to login to previous Gmail ID but other Google services you mentioned like Maps, Books, search history, YouTube, Drive, Docs, Sheets, Photos, etc. will be as it was. They will not be removed and the data inside those services will be as it was.

Comment: `"But only the mails will not be supplied to your new E-mail id as usual."` means I have told that `Google Account` and `Gmail` id are not same. Your previous identity of Google account was your previous `Gmail` id. But after deleting and reassigning the mail id to another one all other services will be transferred to your new e-mail id which will be the new identity of your Google account. But only the mails in your inbox or sent items or drafts etc. of previous gmail id will not be transferred to your new e-mail id.

Comment: If I backup my data, do I need to wait for the archive to complete before proceeding (it can take quite a while, apparently)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Before proceeding for what??

Comment: With the rest of set 1 (and so on). That is: does proceeding with the deletion of my current e-mail disrupt the archiving process that I've started (but that has not yet completed), or with that proceed undisturbed?

Comment: Yes, if you delete your current gmail, then may be you will not be able to get the backup. You should try to delete your gmail after getting the download links of backup to your mail.

Comment: And (hopefully the last clarification before I proceed) is anything about these instructions changed if the new e-mail I wish to use is a Gmail one?

Comment: Sorry, you can not do that with a new Gmail account. In my answer, you can see from the screenshot there it is clearly said. The reason is for a new Gmail id another google account is already created. So, you must have to proceed with E-mail id from other vendors.

Comment: Cool. Understood.